# iOS7 HTML5 Video Poster Not Working

Tags: ios, html, video, ios7

I am using the correct VIDEO Tag for displaying HTML5 Video. The Poster appears fine for earlier iOS versions. However, for iOS7, The poster is not being picked up.

Here is my code

`<video onclick="this.play();" width="100%" height="100%"  preload="none"  poster="[My Poster URL]" src="[My Video URL]"  controls ></video>`

Has anyone tried this? Any help is appreicated.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use a jpg-file as poster? We had the same problem and fixed it by using a png-file. Hope that helps.

Comment: I have seen other reports of this fixing the problem, but I didn't find it made any difference for me.